# get highligthing part ace editor

Tags: javascript, highlight, ace-editor

Could anyone please tell me if I can get the Highlight of multiples lines when I am on a specific line?

I create a hightlight where I have block comments "/**/" in multiple lines. I also have variables, structures and reserved words highlighters that can be into a "block comment".

I have the next "hightlight rules":

```
"dialog_string_start": [
            {
                token : "keyword", 
                regex : /acts\s+/, 
                next : "dialog_acts"
            },
            {
                token : "cadena-a-traducir", 
                regex : /\S/, 
                next : "dialog"
            },
            {   
                defaultToken : "string", 
                caseInsensitive: true
            }
        ],
        "dialog_acts": [
            {
                token : "text", 
                regex : /[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\,\s]+/, 
                next : "dialog_string_start"
            },
            {   
                defaultToken : "text", 
                caseInsensitive: true
            }
        ],
        "dialog": [
            {
                token : "cadena-a-traducir", 
                regex : /$|^/, 
                next : "start"
            },
            {   
                defaultToken : "cadena-a-traducir", 
                caseInsensitive: true
            }
        ],
        "multi_line_comment": [
            {
                token : "comment", 
                regex : /\*\//, 
                next : "start"
            },
            {   
                defaultToken : "comment", 
                caseInsensitive: true
            }
        ],
        "single_line_comment": [
            {
                token : "comment", 
                regex : /$|^/, 
                next : "start"
            },
            {   
                defaultToken : "comment", 
                caseInsensitive: true
            }
        ]// this is only a part
```

In the app, I can "open files" from github and change the text from "dialog" and "dialog_inline" hightlights.

When I open a file, I loop the content using the same expresions found in these lines.

So far the work is ok. The problem that I am facing is that I don't know how to check if a "dialog" is into a comment-block like this:

```
/* start comment
my dialogs' line
```

When I check these kind of lines, I would need to check if this is into a comment, ignore it and I don't know how I can do it.

I have tried using the Tokenizer class, and getLineTokens method.
This method return an array but didn't say that this is a "comment block".  it only shows if this is a dialog, or variable or other.
[Here the tokenizer documentation](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=tokenizer)

(Sorry if my english is no good and thanks for reading).

PD: I can't show the app, because im working in a electron desktop app.

Comment: Could you upload the code that does the highlighting and the code for the comments block?

Comment: the question in this form is likely to be closed, because it doesn't describe a problem in any understandable manner. And it is more about your code than code from ace. You need to try adding an example page showing the issue

Comment: @Thanasis ready the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code in this [link](http://foo123.github.io/examples/ace-grammar/) and I think it is what you are looking for:

```
"comment"                      
: {"type":"comment","tokens":[
  // line comment
  // start, end delims  (null matches end-of-line)
  [  "//",  null ],
  // block comments
  // start,  end    delims
  [  "/*",   "*/" ]
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks is no possible read the final background token while the editor is loading and replacing. I could'nt check the translated lines instead.

Well, how i coundn't do this. My solution (for now) was, check the background tokens on the first click in the ace editor. At that moment, the lines tokens are really loaded and i can check it out.

```
     checkGutters:function(){
        if(!window.checkgutters)
        {
              for (linea in $traductor.gutters){
                    nroLinea = $traductor.gutters[linea];

                    token = $traductor.editorActual.session.bgTokenizer.getTokens(nroLinea);
                    if(typeof(token[0])!='undefined' && token[0].type=='comment')
                    {
                        $traductor.editorActual.session.removeGutterDecoration(nroLinea,'gutter-traduccion');
                    }

                }//fin for
                window.checkgutters=true;
        }
    }
```

In the code, "$traductor" is the javascript object who manage everything on the editor. and "$traductor.editorActual" is the ace editor instance. "$traductor.gutters" is an array were I put the lines where I added gutters before. Then, I loop these array and remove the gutters where the background Token is "comment" . Is the only way that i could fix it.

So, this code, is not able when i am adding the gutters, the line :

```
token = $traductor.editorActual.session.bgTokenizer.getTokens(nroLinea);
```

return "text" and no "comment" before. and when the file is totally loaded and the user clicked on the ace editor the code work good.

Thanks.